# How to assign a String variable to a dataframe name

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I had a problem, which is a for loop program.like below:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]

for index in list:
    new_df_name = "user_" + index
    new_df_name = origin_df1.join(origin_df2,'id','left')
```

but the "**new_df_name**" is just a Variable and String type.

how to realize these?

Comment: If you're trying to append `index` to `user_`, try this: `new_df_name = "user_" + str(index)`

Comment: But dataframe join cannot return a string type name.

new_df_name_df = "user_" + region
new_df_name_df = user_profile_region.join(shopee_backend_user_df, 'userid', 'left')
it cannot be run.

Comment: You could use a list that you append the dataframes to and then reduce it to a single one. Or you could create the result_df iterativly in the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, what you really need is to have a list of dataframes (which non necessary have any specific names) and then union them all together.

```
dataframes = [df1, df2, df3, etc... ]

res_df, tail_dfs = dataframes[0], dataframes[1:]
for df in tail_dfs:
  res_df = res_df.unionAll(df)
```

upd.
even better option to union described in comment.

Comment: or without indexing: `res_df = reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), dataframes)`