# How to specify the name of a dataframe in a variable (string, dict. item)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, variables

I have separated my data into four dataframes (SE_df, SO_df, etc; each matching a specific pattern on one of the columns of the original data). I want to run the same process on each of the four.

I tried something like this (Note: the actual process is longer, but it starts with `value_counts`.)

```
lookup_table = {
    'SE': [SE_df, 'SE_df_counts'],
    'SO': [SO_df, 'SO_df_counts'],
    'OC': [OC_df, 'OC_df_counts'],
    'CW': [CW_df, 'CW_df_counts'] 
}

for site in ['SE', 'SO', 'OC', 'CW']:
    dframe_in = lookup_table[site][0]
    dframe_out = lookup_table[site][1]

    dframe_out = dframe_in.apply(pd.value_counts)
    # ...
```

When the loop finishes, I want four new DataFrames: SE_df_counts, SO_df_counts, ... etc

Instead, I have one new DataFrame named `dframe_out`.

I initially tried to use

```
lookup_table = {
    'SE': [SE_df, SE_df_counts],
    ...
    }
```

but python complained that a DataFrame named `SE_df_counts` didn't exist yet.

I tried forcing it to exist (whoch made the code more brittle, but it was worth a shot).

```
SE_df_counts = pd.DataFrame()
lookup_table = {
    'SE': [df_SE_mic, SE_df_counts],
}

for site in ['SE']:
    dframe_in = lookup_table[site][0]
    dframe_out = lookup_table[site][1]

    dframe_out = dframe_in.apply(pd.value_counts)
```

and I still ended up with a DataFrame named dframe_out (which really confused me).

Is there a way to pass the desired name of a dataframe as a variable (or a dictionary value)?  I see many tempting recommendations here where people say 'Use a dictionary" but the examples are always more complex than what I'm trying to do and the ultimate answers often provide alternate ways around the question. (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284760/how-to-assign-a-string-variable-to-a-dataframe-name) was very close, but the chosen answer wasn't relevant to my use case.)

Comment: you can use `globals()['df_name'] = df`

Comment: so for each of the four dfs you want their respective value counts in new dfs ?

Comment: `lookup_table[site].append(dframe_out)` and then access using `lookup_table[site][2]` ? Although a bad data structure for doing this.

Comment: YOLO >> so for each of the four dfs you want their respective value counts in new dfs?    ----- yes; named by the site.

Comment: Vishnudev - That would be an interesting workaround. I had been thinking of stuffing an empty DataFrame into position[2] if there was no other way. ===>> "Although a bad data structure..." -- what would you recommend instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
lookup_table = {
    'SE': [SE_df, None ],
    'SO': [SO_df, None ],
    'OC': [OC_df, None ],
    'CW': [CW_df, None ] 
}

for site in ['SE', 'SO', 'OC', 'CW']:
    dframe_in = lookup_table[site][0]

    lookup_table[site][1] = dframe_in.apply(pd.value_counts)
```

Comment: Yeah, I've ended up doing something along these lines.  ----- I get the Strong Impression from the replies here and elsewhere that the answer to the question "How do I pass the name of a variable using a {string,variable,dictionary value, ...} is "You can't do that in Python. :-(